# Flow of a XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

I got a question about the program flow of a XSLT transformation. I have the following XML:

```
<Telefonliste>
    <Eintrag att="1">
        <name>Peter</name>
        <nachname>Pan</nachname>
        <Tel>12345</Tel>
    </Eintrag>
    <Eintrag>
        <name>Max</name>
        <nachname>Mustermann</nachname>
        <Tel>98765</Tel>
    </Eintrag>
</Telefonliste>
```

And there is a xsl file A:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    Root node
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    Root node
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*" >
    <xsl:text>Test</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

And there is a xsl file B:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    Root node
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    Root node
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*" >
    <xsl:value-of select="self::node()" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

The Output of A is:

```
Root node
Test
Root node
```

This is exactly what I would suggest of that transformation. First the template for the root is called, prints "Root node" and then applies the template to child::node() (there is no select in the apply-templates clause). Then it calls the second template which prints a single time "Test". Then the template of the root node prints again "Root node" and then the transformation is finished.

If I run transformation B, i get the following output:

```
Root node
Peter
Pan
12345
Max
Mustermann
98765
Root node
```

The printing of "Root node" is clear here. But why dies  prints ALL children node values? I can not understand it, there is no  loop. I would expect only one value, the value of the current context node...

Can someone explain that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following stylesheet:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml"/>

<xsl:template match="/Telefonliste">
    Root node
     <xsl:value-of select="self::node()" />
    Root node
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Applied to your input, the result will be the same as in your transformation  B.

The reason for this is that the `xsl:value-of` instruction returns the [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) of the selected node - and this string-value includes **all** descendant text nodes.

Comment: Is there somewhere a explanation, why that value includes ALL descendent text nodes? I would expect that behaviour, if I do a path expression like ".//*" - I am realy confused

Comment: It is prescribed by the [XPath specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes): *The string-value of an element node is the concatenation of the string-values of all text node descendants of the element node in document order.*

Answer (score 0):

XSLT processor reads XML tree starting at Document Node (/). For both stylesheets (A and B) the first template executed will be template that matches /.
 The template for **/** will output text *Root node* and will execute templates (xsl:appy-templates) to all the children of Document Node (/). Document node for your XML has one child element *Telephonist*.

Your stylesheets A and B do not have a template that matches *Telefonliste* exactly, so template that matches any node (node()|@*) will be used for element *Telefonliste*.

For stylesheet A template for node()|@* will generate output *Test*. XSLT processor will return to the template for Document Node **/** to output the second  *Root node* .

Your stylesheet B template for node()|@* will output all PCData from element *Telefonliste* does not matter how deep excluding attributes.